# Running more functions at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'd like to run one function or both functions A and B at the same time depending if corresponding checkboxes `c_A` and `c_B` are chcecked or not. I'd also like to stop all (one or two) running functions by cliking stop button. I tried following code. It wokrs when only one chceck  box is chcecked. When both chceckboxes are chcecked just function A runs. The running function doesn't stop when I press the stop button.

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
       ThreadStart ts_A = delegate()
                {
                };
                if (c_A.Checked)
                {
                    t_A = new Thread(ts_A);
                    t_A.Start();
                    function_A();
                }

                   ThreadStart ts_B = delegate()
                {
                };
                if (c_B.Checked)
                {
                    t_B = new Thread(ts_B);
                    t_B.Start();
                    function_B();
                }
         }

       private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           t_A.Abort();
           t_B.Abort();
        }
```

Comment: Your `ts_A` and `ts_B` are pointing to empty delegates. Which does not do anything useful. if you wanted to call `function_a` and `function_b` be executed in corresponding thread then wrap a call statement in those delegate.

Comment: Please **never** call `Abort()` on a thread unless you are in the process of shutting down your app. Calling it is dangerous otherwise. Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/259769

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your methods in a Thread at all. You are actually calling it out of the Thread.

In order for it to be called within the thread, the method should be passed within ThreadStart.

```
ThreadStart ts_A = new ThreadStart(function_A);
```

Then calling t_A.Start would run the function_A in a thread. You can find more information on ThreadStart here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Having said that, your method should look like this.

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
   ThreadStart ts_A = new ThreadStart(function_A);
            if (c_A.Checked)
            {
                t_A = new Thread(ts_A);
                t_A.Start();

            }

               ThreadStart ts_B = new ThreadStart(function_B);
            if (c_B.Checked)
            {
                t_B = new Thread(ts_B);
                t_B.Start();

            }
     }
```